# Printing map object when it is locked by mutex

Tags: go, concurrency, locking, mutex, waitgroup

I am not sure why mutex is not working as I expected. Any advice will help me.

Here is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

type Container struct {
    mu       sync.Mutex
    counters map[string]int
}

func (c *Container) inc(name string) {
    c.mu.Lock()
    defer c.mu.Unlock()
    c.counters[name]++
    
    // fmt.Println("in", name, c.counters) 
    // This print is doing tricks between goroutines
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
}

func main() {
    c := Container{

        counters: map[string]int{"a": 0, "b": 0},
    }

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    doIncrement := func(name string, n int) {
        for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            c.inc(name)
            fmt.Println(name, c.counters)
        }
        wg.Done()
    }

    wg.Add(3)
    go doIncrement("a", 2)
    go doIncrement("b", 2)
    go doIncrement("a", 2)

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(c.counters)
}
```

When I ran this, I got strange outputs.

```
a map[a:2 b:0]
a map[a:2 b:0]
b map[a:2 b:1]
a map[a:4 b:1]
a map[a:4 b:1]
b map[a:4 b:2]
map[a:4 b:2]
```

I expected some logs where I can see `a` increased to 1,2,3,4

When I removed comments in `inc` function;
I could see the expected logs.

```
in a map[a:1 b:0]
a map[a:1 b:0]
in a map[a:2 b:0]
a map[a:2 b:0]
in b map[a:2 b:1]
b map[a:2 b:1]
in a map[a:3 b:1]
a map[a:3 b:1]
in a map[a:4 b:1]
a map[a:4 b:1]
in b map[a:4 b:2]
b map[a:4 b:2]
map[a:4 b:2]
```

Comment: This is not proper usage of the mutex because you read the map (`fmt.Println(name, c.counters)`) without holding the lock.

Comment: A mutex does not provide any guarantees of the order of execution of code across different goroutines. It only assures **mut**ual **ex**clusion of the code block(s) protected by `Lock` and `Unlock`, nothing more.

Comment: I understand what you mean, but why it is working as I expected when I add another printf in `inc` function?

Comment: By printing before the `time.Sleep`, you make it significantly less likely (not impossible) that the time between increment and print of one goroutine will overlap with the increment of another goroutine.

Comment: so the point is multiple goroutines already increased but because of sleep, we get multiple increased value inside the loop.  all clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this loop:

```
for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
            c.inc(name)  ---> This runs with mutex locked
            fmt.Println(name, c.counters)  --> This runs with mutex unlocked
}
```

The Println runs outside the mutex lock. Two goroutines attempt to increment "a" at the same time, one increments and then waits. When that increment function returns, the second one goes in and increments, then Println from the first one runs, then Println from the second one prints the same thing.

So, mutex is working as expected, but you are printing outside the region protected by mutex.

Comment: So println with mutex unlocked is printing unexpected values because the map object is locked in other goroutines??

Comment: No it is printing the value after both goroutines update it.

Comment: The operations are: g1 increment, g2 increnent, g1 print, g2 print